# How do I install a specific version of Erlang/OTP?

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, vagrant, rabbitmq

I have inherited a project with a puppet/vagrant/Virtual box setup. The vagrant provision is breaking around my erlangs surrounding rabbitmq-server.

the error:

```
==> default: err: /Stage[main]/Rabbitmq::Install/Package[rabbitmq-server]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install rabbitmq-server' returned 100: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
==> default: requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
==> default: distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
==> default: or been moved out of Incoming.
==> default: The following information may help to resolve the situation:
==> default:
==> default: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
==> default:  rabbitmq-server : Depends: erlang-nox (>= 1:16.b.3) but it is not going to be installed or
==> default:                             esl-erlang but it is not installable
==> default:                    Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.13~) but it is not installable
==> default: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have gone through the steps listed `http://www.scotthelm.com/2013/11/27/rabbit-mq-and-erlang-and-ubuntu-oh-my.html`. I installed erlang and erlagn-nox, but when i run `erl` my version shows as R14B04 when i want the r16 that rabbitmq plays well with. How do I install a specific version of erlang?

Currently I have tried `sudo apt-get install erlang=1:16.b.3-dfsg-1ubuntu2` but it can't be found. Have tried several variations but no luck. My other idea is to download the tar itself and build it, but this seems excessive and it seems like I am missing something more obvious.

Comment: Have you tried the [official guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html)?

Comment: what is the ubuntu version you are using ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I destroyed the machine and did it again with just ```sudo apt-get install erlang``` and it worked. However, before doing this, the official guide @AlexBuyny suggested, I installed the erlang-esl that the guide suggests and it worked as well. No idea why no command would update the erlang correctly in that particular machine.

Answer (score 33):

you cau use Erlang-Solutions repositories:

```
wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install esl-erlang=1:19.3.6
```

Comment: why i am getting this 
after doing this
 sudo apt-get install esl-erlang=1:19.3.6

"E: Version '1:19.3.6' for 'esl-erlang' was not found
"

Comment: for anybody who has the same problem as mentioned above "... esl-erlang was not found ". Please check with the following command the available packages apt-cache policy esl-erlang. for now there is only 1:19.3.6.8 or 1:19.3.6.12-1 that's what you should use. TL;DR: sudo apt-get install esl-erlang=1:19.3.6.8

Answer (score 5):

**1. Remove previous Erlang versions/packages:**

```
$ sudo apt-get purge erlang esl-erlang erlang-base erlang-crypto erlang-eldap erlang-inets erlang-mnesia erlang-os-mon
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get install -f

$ sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/erlang
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ sudo rm -f erl
$ sudo rm -f erlc
$ sudo rm -f epmd
$ sudo rm -f run_erl
$ sudo rm -f to_erl
$ sudo rm -f dialyzer
$ sudo rm -f typer
$ sudo rm -f escript
$ sudo rm -f ct_run
```

**2. Add the repository entry manually:**

- To get Ubuntu codename type `$ lsb_release -c`. In my case it's **xenial**.
- `$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and add following text at the end of the file:

```
# Erlang Solutions
deb https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu xenial contrib
```

- Create a file **/etc/apt/preferences.d/erlang** :

```
$ sudo touch /etc/apt/preferences.d/erlang
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/erlang
```

with the following contents:

```
Package: erlang* esl-erlang
Pin: version 1:21.3*
Pin-Priority: 501
```

where *21.3* is the version of Erlang/OTP.

**3. Install Erlang:**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install esl-erlang
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/erlang/bin/erl /usr/local/bin/erl
```

**4. Check installed Erlang version:**

```
$ erl -eval '{ok, Version} = file:read_file(filename:join([code:root_dir(), "releases", erlang:system_info(otp_release), "OTP_VERSION"])), io:fwrite(Version), halt().' -noshell
```

---

**Related link:** https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**kerl**](https://github.com/kerl/kerl) to install different Erlang/OTP on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

First download the required version from http://erlang.org/download

```
wget http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R16B01.tar.gz
tar -xvzf otp_src_R16B01.tar.gz
sudo chmod -R 777 otp_src_R16B01
cd otp_src_R16B01
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

All the best

Comment: I am getting following error in ./configure command... configure: error: No curses library functions found
configure: error: /bin/bash '/home/username/otp_src_R16B01/erts/configure' failed for erts

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev`
https://github.com/kerl/kerl/issues/17#issuecomment-353278420

Answer (score 1):

You may also check solution called EVM

here is the detailed information : https://github.com/robisonsantos/evm

Answer (score 0):

Install Erlang

```
cd /tmp/

wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb

sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install erlang -y


Install RabbitMQ from source

cd /tmp/

echo 'echo "deb http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian/ testing main" >> 
/etc/apt/sources.list' | sudo -s

wget https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc

sudo apt-key add rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc

sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y
```