# Remove or downgrade Erlang from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, phoenix-framework

I installed the Erlang/OPT 20 in my OS and the phoenix framework show the following error message:

When I run the command:

```
 iex -S mix
```

I get:

```
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

** (Version.InvalidRequirementError) ~> 1.3 or ~> 1.4
    (elixir) lib/version.ex:159: Version.match?/3
    (mix) lib/mix/local.ex:100: Mix.Local.check_elixir_version_in_ebin/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:645: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:645: Enum.each/2
    (mix) lib/mix/local.ex:50: Mix.Local.append_archives/0
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:8: Mix.CLI.main/1
```

I had the Erlang 19 before and after the upgrade it broke the phoenix. To downgrade to the older version I tried to install it manually after download from the [official website](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html) I couldn't replace with the installer (the system understands that the newer is better so don't ask to substitute).

Then I tried to remove it completely using this command line:

```
sudo apt-get purge erlang
```

and for my surprise it doens't remove:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'erlang' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

"**Package 'erlang' is not installed, so not removed**"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem with this command lines:

```
wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb       
sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install esl-erlang=1:19.3.6
```

I got from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44685813/how-do-i-install-a-specific-version-of-erlang)

Comment: running the last command on Ubuntu shows the following error:
E: Version '1:19.3.6' for 'esl-erlang' was not found.
any pointers?

Comment: for anybody who has the same problem as mentioned above "... esl-erlang was not found ". Please check with the following command the available packages
 apt-cache policy esl-erlang
There is only 1:19.3.6.8 or 1:19.3.6.12-1 that's what you should use.
TL;DR:  sudo apt-get install esl-erlang=1:19.3.6.8

Answer (score 2):

I solved by following way

**upgrading/downgrade erlang version**

https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf

**upgrading/downgrade elixir version**

$ git clone https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir.git

$ cd elixir

$ git checkout v1.6 (v1.4,v1.5,v1.7) //for downgrading or upgrading

$ sudo apt-get install make

$ make clean test

$ sudo make install

$ elixir -v