# Erlang dependencies issue while installing RabbitMq on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, erlang

I am trying to install rabbitmq on my ubuntu version 16.04.5 machine.

I followed multiple ways to install but getting some dependencies issues every time.

I followed

https://tecadmin.net/install-erlang-on-ubuntu/

and

[How do I install a specific version of erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44685813/how-do-i-install-a-specific-version-of-erlang/54474164#54474164)

Every time I am getting same error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 erlang : Depends: erlang-diameter but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-eldap but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-ftp but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-tftp but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: erlang-jinterface but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: erlang-ic-java but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: erlang-mode but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: erlang-src but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: erlang-examples but it is not going to be installed
 esl-erlang : Depends: libwxbase2.8-0 but it is not installable or
                       libwxbase3.0-0 but it is not installable or
                       libwxbase3.0-0v5 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0 but it is not installable or
                       libwxgtk3.0-0 but it is not installable or
                       libwxgtk3.0-0v5 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libsctp1 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: erlang-mode but it is not going to be installed
 rabbitmq-server : Depends: erlang-base (>= 1:20.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                            erlang-base-hipe (>= 1:20.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:20.3)
                   Depends: erlang-crypto (>= 1:20.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:20.3)
                   Depends: erlang-eldap (>= 1:20.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:20.3)
                   Depends: erlang-inets (>= 1:20.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:20.3)
                   Depends: erlang-mnesia (>= 1:20.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:20.3)
                   Depends: erlang-os-mon (>= 1:20.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:20.3)
                   Depends: erlang-parsetools (>= 1:20.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:20.3)
                   Depends: erlang-public-key (>= 1:20.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:20.3)
                   Depends: erlang-runtime-tools (>= 1:20.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:20.3)
                   Depends: erlang-ssl (>= 1:20.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:20.3)
                   Depends: erlang-syntax-tools (>= 1:20.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:20.3)
                   Depends: erlang-tools (>= 1:20.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:20.3)
                   Depends: erlang-xmerl (>= 1:20.3) or
                            esl-erlang (>= 1:20.3)
                   Depends: socat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Did you try running `apt-get -f install`? What did it say?

Answer (score 4):

Running the below commands will resolve the error and install erlang successfully

```
echo 'deb https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu xenial contrib' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu/erlang_solutions.asc

sudo apt-key add erlang_solutions.asc

apt update && apt install esl-erlang
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems like you might either have to install those dependencies manually (e.g., [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/606896/594870)) or use esl-erlang, which bundles at least some of them for you.

The latter worked at least for my case, where all I was missing was `erlang-ftp` and `erlang-tftp`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 erlang : Depends: erlang-appmon
          Depends: erlang-ftp but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-gs
          Depends: erlang-inviso
          Depends: erlang-percept
          Depends: erlang-pman
          Depends: erlang-test-server
          Depends: erlang-tftp but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-toolbar
          Depends: erlang-tv
          Depends: erlang-typer
```

esl-erlang is just the complete installation, as described in the faq given [here](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/).

**In short, my command looked like this** (for v.23.3.1):

```
apt-get install esl-erlang=1:23.3.1-1
```